# Toggle a attribute with id 'user'+i with a checkbox with id 'checkbox'+i

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

first thanks for your help in advance.
I'm pretty newbie in jquery and javascript and I don't speak so much english so i cound't found nothing liked in my research.

This is my html

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li id="user1"></li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">

<li></li>
<li></li>
<li id="user2"></li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
```

I want to everytime that a checkbox with id ("checkbox"+i) is checked I toggle a class in the ("user"+i) to push in a list and then send with post request.

I tryed this

```
for(i = 1; i < 3; i++) {    
   document.getElementById('checkbox' + i).addEventListener('change', function() {
        document.getElementById('user' + i).setAttribute("class", "passInterestIds");
  });
}
```

but it only gives me user3 independent of the checkbox

How can I Make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: I tried some function outside but It still gave me user3, somethimes they got undefined, thanks for the help, gonna read a bit more

Comment: It's because you have a global `i` try and do `for(var i = 0; ...` instead of `for(i = 0; ...`.

Comment: And my personal favorite answer from the duplicate link is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19324832/6647153!

Comment: i tried to create  function user(j) {return('user'+j)}and executed when with function(){user(i)} but still didn't work.

Comment: Thanks gonna read a little more about see what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this will always work as long as the id contains ONE digit cause that what we're taking from the match function. Then if checkbox gets checked add class `hello` else remove class `hello`

```js
var elements = $('input[type^=checkbox');
elements.on('click', function(){
  var idNr = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0];
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#user' + idNr).addClass('hello');
  } else {
    $('#user' + idNr).removeClass('hello');
  }
});
```

```css
.hello {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="user1"></li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">

<li id="user2"></li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
```

If possible to change the HTML.. The better way would be to use the value attribute from the input element containing the number. Or use a `data-user-id` attribute if you can not use the value attribute.

```js
var elements = $('input[type^=checkbox');
elements.on('click', function(){
  var idNr = $(this).val();
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#user' + idNr).addClass('hello');
  } else {
    $('#user' + idNr).removeClass('hello');
  }
});
```

```css
.hello {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="user1"></li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1">

<li id="user2"></li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"  value="2">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked and the most important I understood, didn't know that you how to  use regexp with javascript it's gonna help me a lot with this project.

Comment: Sorry don't have enough reputation, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @LuizFernandoLobo you do not need any reputation to mark as accepted .. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work